# Asp.Net webapi : throw new RestException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I am a beginner developer and I have an issue in Query handler when using  `throw new RestException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)`
this is my query handler:

```
namespace Application.User
{
       public class Login
       {
          public class Query : IRequest<AppUser>
          {
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public string Password { get; set; }
           }

        public class QueryValidator : AbstractValidator<Query>
        {
            public QueryValidator()
            {
                RuleFor(x => x.Email).NotEmpty();
                RuleFor(x => x.Password).NotEmpty();
            }
        }
        public class Handler : IRequestHandler<Query, AppUser>
        {
            private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;
            private readonly SignInManager<AppUser> _signUserManager;
            public Handler(UserManager<AppUser> userManager, SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager)
            {
                _userManager = userManager;
                _signUserManager = signInManager;
            }

            public async Task<AppUser> Handle(Query request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(request.Email);

                if (user == null)

                    throw new RestException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);



                var result = await _signUserManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, request.Password, false);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    //TODO : generate token
                    return user;
                }

                throw new RestException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when i using throw new RestException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized); i give 401 error and i do not know haw can i resolve this

Comment: 401error is because HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized is 401.If you don't want to get the error,you need tou make sure `user != null` and `result.Succeeded`.In other words,you need to make sure Email and Password are right.Or you will get a 401 error.Also If you don't throw RestException,you will not get 401 error.